# Access LOB value with cx_Oracle and ORA-22922 error

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm trying to access the value of a LOB returned by a procedure with `cx_Oracle`. LOB is the first field of tuple (`'reg[0]'`).

When I do this:

```
regs = cursor.fetchall()
for reg in regs:
    print reg[0]
```

The following error happens:

`DatabaseError: ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value`

And when I try to use read() method (`reg[0].read()` instead of `print reg[0]`), but the error is the same.

How can I access the LOB value in this case?

Comment: [The cx_Oracle documentation advises against using `fetchall` with LOBs](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/lob.html).  Does it help if you write `for reg in cursor` instead of reading all of the data into a list and then printing it out?  (Incidentally I can't reproduce your error; I can only reproduce the error mention in the cx_Oracle link above.  I'm using Oracle XE 11.2.0.2.0, Python 2.7.3 and cx_Oracle 5.1.2, if that helps.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using sqlalchemy Session and executing the command directly in Session instead of a cursor.

When I created a cursor and did `cursor.execute(procedure)`, I got access to LOB content with read() method as desired.